# Java to Google Spreadsheet

Tags: java, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I was trying to do programming using Java to connect to Google Spreadsheet to do data retrieval or modifying data in the cells.

My Google spreadsheet link is https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UXoGD2gowxZ2TY3gooI9y7rwWTPBOA0dnkeNYwUqQRA

I looked at the [Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/) and it requires link like

`https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/worksheets/key/private/full`

I have tried different forms of the links, such as:

1. `https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/worksheets/1UXoGD2gowxZ2TY3gooI9y7rwWTPBOA0dnkeNYwUqQRA/private/full`
2. `https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/worksheets/1UXoGD2gowxZ2TY3gooI9y7rwWTPBOA0dnkeNYwUqQRA/private/full`

They gave me different kinds of errors respectively:

1. `com.google.gdata.util.ParseException: Unrecognized content type:application/binary`
2. `com.google.gdata.util.RedirectRequiredException: Moved Temporarily`

I have no idea how to connect to the Googl Spreadsheet using Java. Please help me if you have experience on this.

```
import com.google.gdata.client.authn.oauth.*;
import com.google.gdata.client.spreadsheet.*;
import com.google.gdata.data.*;
import com.google.gdata.data.batch.*;
import com.google.gdata.data.spreadsheet.*;
import com.google.gdata.util.*;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;

public class TestGoogleSheetsAPI {

    @Test
    public void testConnectToSpreadSheet() throws ServiceException, IOException {
        SpreadsheetService service = new SpreadsheetService("google-spreadsheet");

        URL SPREADSHEET_FEED_URL = new URL("https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/worksheets/1UXoGD2gowxZ2TY3gooI9y7rwWTPBOA0dnkeNYwUqQRA/public/full");
        SpreadsheetFeed feed = service.getFeed(SPREADSHEET_FEED_URL, SpreadsheetFeed.class);
        List<SpreadsheetEntry> spreadsheets = feed.getEntries();

        if (spreadsheets.size() == 0) {
            // TODO: There were no spreadsheets, act accordingly.
        }

        SpreadsheetEntry spreadsheet = spreadsheets.get(0);
        System.out.println(spreadsheet.getTitle().getPlainText());
    }
}
```

I didn't use `service.setUserCredentials("xxx@gmail", "password")` because I will have another error, which is `com.google.gdata.util.AuthenticationException: Error authenticating (check service name)`

Comment: Did you set up the Java client library?  Or are you using raw REST HTTPS requests?

Comment: I used maven to import the gdata library. Should I actually download the JAR file instead?

Comment: I don't know.  I just wanted to make sure that you'd done the basics.  Please show the Java code that is making the request.

Comment: added the code above

Comment: I think you need to authenticate using oauth. the url `https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds` is under the scope of oauth information. check here for more https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/

Answer (score 3):

You are getting the redirect because accessing your spreadsheet requires that you authenticate first. Google Sheets is using the old gdata API, but requires that you authenticate using OAuth 2.0. Therefore you will need to import both the gdata and Google API libraries as shown below:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.gdata</groupId>
        <artifactId>core</artifactId>
        <version>1.47.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-api-client-java6</artifactId>
        <version>1.20.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

The code below shows how you can authenticate with Google using OAuth. You will need to [follow the instructions for creating a service account and downloading the P12 key first.](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount) After creating your service account, copy the email address into the CLIENT_ID field below, add your P12 file to your classpath and chante P12FILE to point to your P12 file.

I was able to get this working with the following SPREADSHEET_FEED_URL "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/worksheets/:worksheetId/private/basic" where ":worksheetId" is your worksheet Id. This is slightly different than the one you were using.

Be sure to make sure that your service account has permission to read or write to the spreadsheet by sharing it with the service account email address first.

```
public class GoogleSheetsApiTest {

// Generate a service account and P12 key:
// https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount
private final String CLIENT_ID = "<your service account email address>";
// Add requested scopes.
private final List<String> SCOPES = Arrays
        .asList("https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds");
// The name of the p12 file you created when obtaining the service account
private final String P12FILE = "/<your p12 file name>.p12";


@Test
public void testConnectToSpreadSheet() throws GeneralSecurityException,
        IOException, ServiceException, URISyntaxException {

    SpreadsheetService service = new SpreadsheetService(
            "google-spreadsheet");
    GoogleCredential credential = getCredentials();
    service.setOAuth2Credentials(credential);

    URL SPREADSHEET_FEED_URL = new URL(
            "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/worksheets/1UXoGD2gowxZ2TY3gooI9y7rwWTPBOA0dnkeNYwUqQRA/private/basic");
    SpreadsheetFeed feed = service.getFeed(SPREADSHEET_FEED_URL,
            SpreadsheetFeed.class);
    List<SpreadsheetEntry> spreadsheets = feed.getEntries();

    if (spreadsheets.size() == 0) {
        // // TODO: There were no spreadsheets, act accordingly.
    }
    //
    SpreadsheetEntry spreadsheet = spreadsheets.get(0);
    System.out.println(spreadsheet.getTitle().getPlainText());

}

private GoogleCredential getCredentials() throws GeneralSecurityException,
        IOException, URISyntaxException {
    JacksonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
    HttpTransport httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport
            .newTrustedTransport();

    URL fileUrl = this.getClass().getResource(P12FILE);
    GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
            .setTransport(httpTransport)
            .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
            .setServiceAccountId(CLIENT_ID)
            .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(
                    new File(fileUrl.toURI()))
            .setServiceAccountScopes(SCOPES).build();

    return credential;
}

}
```

Comment: Hi Brian, Thanks a lot. I went through Google developer console and created a service account. CLIENT_ID should be the longer one in the developers console, or my real email?

Comment: my code working well now, added `credential.refreshToken();` after `.setServiceAccountScopes(SCOPES).build();`. Really appreciate your help, Brian!

Comment: @TimLai Accept the answer if its working. Others with the same issue will know which answer to look for.

Answer (score 1):

I was also getting the `com.google.gdata.util.ParseException: Unrecognized content type:application/binary` error, but I seem to have stumbled on a workaround for this strange bug. The code in [Alex R's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31526240/873263) can be used as a starting point.

1. First I tried changing the visibility to `"public"`, just to see what would happen. Since the document is not published, I got the expected error response, containing:

   > We're sorry. This document is not published.
2. So I changed the visibility back to `"private"`, and tried again just for fun...

   ***Lo, and behold; it worked!***

It works with either the Drive or Spreadsheets Feed scope (both can be included if you prefer):

- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive
- https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds

I'm not sure if its a factor, but I'm not using OAuth 2.0, but rather a `Credential` created from a `PrivateKey` (PKCS12 file), as in [Brian Chapman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31527352/873263).

**Conclusion**

So, although it's kludgy, I've modified my application to **always** make a `"public"` request (wrapped in a `try` block to absorb the resulting `Exception`) just before making the `"private"` request. It's the only way I've been able to deterministically get the correct result.

Answer (score 0):

The feed you get from that URL is a `WorksheetFeed`, not a `SpreadsheetFeed`.
Try this:

```
    SpreadsheetService service = new SpreadsheetService("google-spreadsheet");

    FeedURLFactory urlFactory = FeedURLFactory.getDefault();
    WorksheetFeed worksheetFeed = service.getFeed(urlFactory.getWorksheetFeedUrl("1V4jT4vSqmY4YNY1VJhariLRLbxfFWf5z8bSTpDcSBPE", "public", "full"), WorksheetFeed.class);
    List<WorksheetEntry> worksheets = worksheetFeed.getEntries();
    WorksheetEntry worksheet = worksheets.get(0);
    System.out.println(worksheet.getTitle().getPlainText());
```

Answer (score 0):

I feel like this is a bug. As a workaround you could invoke below getfeed request first and then your feed requests will start working. below is modified code for better understanding

```
import com.google.gdata.client.authn.oauth.*;
import com.google.gdata.client.spreadsheet.*;

import com.google.gdata.data.*;
import com.google.gdata.data.batch.*;
import com.google.gdata.data.spreadsheet.*;
import com.google.gdata.util.*;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;

public class TestGoogleSheetsAPI {

    @Test
    public void testConnectToSpreadSheet() throws ServiceException, IOException {
        SpreadsheetService service = new SpreadsheetService("google-spreadsheet");

        URL SPREADSHEET_FEED_URL = new URL("https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/worksheets/1UXoGD2gowxZ2TY3gooI9y7rwWTPBOA0dnkeNYwUqQRA/public/full");
        //added new line *******************************
        service.getFeed(new URL("https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/spreadsheets/private/full?xoauth_requestor_id=test"),WorksheetFeed.class);
        //************************
        SpreadsheetFeed feed = service.getFeed(SPREADSHEET_FEED_URL, SpreadsheetFeed.class);
        List<SpreadsheetEntry> spreadsheets = feed.getEntries();

        if (spreadsheets.size() == 0) {
            // TODO: There were no spreadsheets, act accordingly.
        }

        SpreadsheetEntry spreadsheet = spreadsheets.get(0);
        System.out.println(spreadsheet.getTitle().getPlainText());
    }
}
```

Did some debugging as well. Seems if we try to invoke worksheet with key, then response seems to have content type "application/binary" which will be regected in gdata library, but if we try to get all the feeds first then response will have correct content type and that type is used in next requests. so flow starts working

Answer (score 0):

1 reason for getting **com.google.gdata.util.RedirectRequiredException: Moved Temporarily** is when we forget to publish the document/spreadsheet. Make sure you have published your document after creating it by going to Menu > File > Published to Web. This is required only once and not after every edit.