# new error using Google Spreadsheets API (v3)

Tags: google-sheets-api

we have been happily using this API for years in our GAE/J application, but all of a sudden got this error;

```
Caused by: com.google.gdata.util.ParseException: Unrecognized content type:application/binary
```

19hrs ago on our US servers
5hrs ago on our EU servers

any ideas?

Comment: Can you manually set the content type to application/json?

Comment: actually it must have been a Google problem.  It was working again by the end of the day.  Mercifully.

Comment: Error `Caused by: com.google.gdata.util.ParseException: Unrecognized content type:application/binary` might occur if you are not using [OAuth2](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount). You may check it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31507989/java-to-google-spreadsheet). You will need to import both the gdata and Google API libraries. Be sure to make sure that your service account has permission to read or write to the spreadsheet by sharing it with the service account email address first. Hope this helps!